# Where to publish personal Project [Custom Fonts]

Tags: android, ios, fonts

I make a very little framework for Android and iOS.

Its for adding Custom Fonts to the project in iOS it return it like UIImage and in Android like Bitmap.

You could do your fonts with programs like Glyph Designer.

I want to make it as an open Source code. But where could I publish it and give feedback and updates?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [github](https://github.com). It's free for Open Source projects.

Comment: Yes but how the people will know it?

Comment: Create a demo free app for different markets.

Comment: In december i will make a game using this plugin for iOS and Android. But thanks i will upload it and upload a demo project for both